# Changing number of breaks/labels in ggtern

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I'm trying to change the default of 5 breaks to 3 breaks (i.e., axis labels at 33, 67 and 100). I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
ggtern(data = Data1, aes(E,L,H),
       labels_tern(limits = c(0,1), breaks=3,
                   format = "%g", factor = 100),
       breaks_tern(limits = c(0,1),TRUE,n=3))+
  theme_hidegrid_minor()
```

Plot that I'm getting:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works, because the arguments to `limit_tern(...)` get passed through to all of scale_X_continuous (X = T, L, R)

```
library(ggtern)
ggtern() + 
  limit_tern(breaks       = c(1/3,2/3,1.0),
             labels       = c(33,66,100),
             minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image: Output]